# How to change the title of .exe installer

Tags: cmd, installshield-2012, installanywhere

I have created an installer using Installer Anywhere 2012. The installer created have a title(for example "ABC") which I want to change to some other string to make the installer more informative.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All that needs to be done is set the standard [Windows installer property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#product_information_properties) 
 values. I believe the top value in your screenshot is the ProductName property. The next line is the CompanyName property